# Migrate Redshift to another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I need to migrate my Redshift to another region. I can see options that I can copy the snapshot to another region whenever backup happens but that also I cannot explicitly copy the snapshot to another region right now so that I can restore it immediately and then let all my apps connect to new redshift !

What is the best way to achieve this without having any data loss.. Currently my redshift gets updated hourly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have to use the automated cross-region snapshot feature since there is no manual snapshot copy function available. Kick off a manual snapshot with cross-region copy enabled.

Comment: Can anyone give me an estimate of how long it takes to transfer a 1 GB snapshot from us-east-# to us-west-#?

Comment: Just matter of minutes. I just copied a >30GB snapshot from us-west to us-east, went to the toilet, and it is now available.